# Getting Quantity Mysql

Tags: mysql

**QUERY 1(FIRST TABLE - STOCK IN)**

```
select sum(s.liquid_quantity) as 'stock in total' from stockin_detail s 
left join reagent r on r.id = s.reagent_id group by r.name
```

**QUERY 2(SECOND TABLE - STOCK OUT)**

```
select sum(t.consumption)as 'stock out total' ,r.name from stock_out s 
inner join test_consumption t on s.consumption_id = t.id 
inner join reagent r on r.id = t.reagent_id group by r.name
```

QUERY 1

```
stock in  |r.name     
100       |Reagent2                 
100       |Reagent3
```

QUERY 2

```
stock out  |r.name     
40         |Reagent2                 
20         |Reagent3
```

i tried doing this but it wont subtract because each of the nested select statement returns 'more than one column' error message due to group by.
I also tried removing the group by but ended up combing two different stocks then subtracted.

```
SELECT QUERY1 – QUERY2 as ‘current stocks’
```

EXPECTED OUT COME

```
current stock|r.name  
60           |Reagent2                 
80           |Reagent3
```

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: is the Expected Out Come typed incorrectly? Reagent2 with 20 and Reagent3 with 60 would make more sense to me....

Comment: oops sorry . Copied wrong table .thanks.. Edited :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not dump the two queries into inline views and then join them together?

Something like this should get you going. Inline view aliased 'i' is the stock in and inline view aliased 'o' is the stock out:

```
select i.name,i.in-ifnull(o.out,0) as 'current stock'
from
 (
  select sum(s.liquid_quantity) as in,r.name 
  from stockin_detail s 
  left join reagent r on r.id = s.reagent_id 
  group by r.name
 ) i
 left outer join
 (
  select sum(t.consumption)as 'out' ,r.name from stock_out s 
  inner join test_consumption t on s.consumption_id = t.id 
  inner join reagent r on r.id = t.reagent_id 
  group by r.name
 ) o on i.name = o.name;
```

Comment: THANKS IT WORKED. I changed the alias 'in' to 'sin' because in is a built in function in mysql. and it worked. Thanks